# Laravel Image dimensions

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I want the user to upload a rectangular image.
I want to validate if user uploaded a valid rectangular image within recommended size. How can I do this?
Right now I'm using the following

```
$request->validate([

        'image_height' => 'numeric|min:2000|max:4000',
        'image_width' =>  'numeric|min:1000|max:2000',

        'image' => 'required|dimensions:min_height=2000,min_width=1000, max_height=4000,max_width=2000',


    ], $messages);
```

I also want to use this image_height and image_width fields in place of hardcoded sizes in image rule. There is a validation rule Dimensions ratio in laravel documentation. Could anybody tell whats the ratio for a rectangular image?

Comment: the docs are pretty clear  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-dimensions

Comment: The ratio for a rectangular image would depend on its dimensions I guess. From the docs: "_A ratio constraint should be represented as width divided by height._"

Comment: yeah but what its like? how can i restrict user to upload 1000*2000 or 2000*4000? height is double the size of width. what would be the ratio? 1/2

Answer (score 0):

You will not achieve this by standard validators; you need to write your own custom validator

Comment: custom validation for what? for checking the dimensions or checking if image is rectangular?

Comment: @AHSAN As I realized that you need to load only rectangular images. This means that you need to check that one side (height or width) is greater than the other. To do this, you need to write your validator